# click function is not working on element which has been appended to body using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following tag in my page

Timeline
and have used folling jquery code

```
$(".timeline").click(function(){createtip(eventdata);});

function createtip(eventdata){ 

    $('<div class="tip"></div>').appendTo('body').html(html_content);
        positionTooltip(eventdata);        
    };

    function positiontip(eventdata){
        var PosX = eventdata.pageX;
        var PosY = eventdata.pageY;
        $('div.tip').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': PosY, 'left': PosX});
```

and the html_content is:

```
<input type="button" class="button" name="submit_tooltip_form" value="close"/>
```

after appending the div tag i am trying to close this div tag by clicking the button which is inside div tag .i am not sure what to do because i am new to jquery .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yN2Qn/)

When you add new content to a document, it will be added without any event handlers, like `click()` or `on( 'click' )` . This means you have to do one of two things:

either bind the event to the new objects after they've been added, like this:

```
$(newElement).on('click',  function () {
    $(this).closest('.tip').hide();
   // other stuff
});
```

or instead, you can delegate the click handling to a parent object, which will automatically handle events for newly added elements, like so:

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.button', function () {
    $(this).closest('.tip').hide();
});
```

If you use the second method, you don't need to worry about binding events to new objects.

note: you may want to remove the tips rather than hiding them ? in which case substitute `.remove()` for `.hide()` in the above example

Comment: i have tried this but not working. i want to close the appended div tag on clicking the button which is inside appended div tag

Comment: The second function should work on added elements. I've changed it to reflect your comments below. Note: this function should called once, and should handle all added buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function createtip(eventdata){ 
        $('body').append('<div class="tip">'+html_content+'</div>');
        positionTooltip(eventdata);        
    };
```

Comment: You are multiplying events on each element that was already appended - not the best option.

Comment: i have already appended this .now i want to remove using button which is inside of appended div tag

Comment: i have following code for closing appended div class     $(".button").click(function(eventdata){$(".tip").hide();})

Answer (score 0):

try using [jquery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(".timeline").on('click',function(){
    createtip(eventdata);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('input [name="submit_tooltip_form"]').live("click", function(){
    $(".tip").hide();
});
```